# make the border thicker and change color or give shadow effect on awesome-bootstrap-checkbox?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I am using 3 [awesome-bootstrap-checkboxes](https://github.com/flatlogic/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox) without label.
My client wants different colors for the checkboxes before they are checked. 
I tried to change `border-color` and `box-shadow` but this does not work. ( Yes I am not good in css. ) Frankly I don't know what target object I should give as css effect.

Is it possible to make the borders of awesome-check-boxes thicker and change their color? Or add a shadow effect to the border of the checkbox?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox/0.3.7/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="styled styled-primary" id="singleCheckbox2" value="option2" aria-label="Single checkbox Two">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-warning">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="styled styled-primary" id="singleCheckbox2" value="option2" aria-label="Single checkbox Two">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-danger">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="styled styled-primary" id="singleCheckbox2" value="option2" aria-label="Single checkbox Two">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
```

It changes like this after check action (see image). But I want to make checkbox always like this. (before it is checked. Always in normal status)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below `css` for override `awesome-bootstrap-checkbox`

```css
.checkbox {
    margin:15px;
}
.checkbox label::before {
    border: 1px solid #0095ff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 2px #0095ff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox/0.3.7/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="styled styled-primary" id="singleCheckbox2" value="option2" aria-label="Single checkbox Two">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-warning">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="styled styled-primary" id="singleCheckbox2" value="option2" aria-label="Single checkbox Two">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-danger">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="styled styled-primary" id="singleCheckbox2" value="option2" aria-label="Single checkbox Two">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Hiren Vaghasiya!!